Why does a QUIT in dead code of an SQL Server script execute anyway?
I have this simple SQL Server script that does what it should, but adding an QUIT statement in one condition ends the script no matter what! I can toggle the flag in line 2 and will get 'ON' and 'OFF' as output, as expected. However, if I activate the QUIT statement in line 6, the script will end without printing 'ON', even if the flag is 1 and the condition isn't supposed to be executed at all!
DECLARE @Flag BIT;
SET @Flag = 1;        -- toggle this
IF @Flag = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'OFF';
    --QUIT            -- uncomment this and it will always QUIT!
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'ON';
END;

I run the script with the command sqlcmd -i test.sql.
Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

You marked your question with Microsoft SQL Server tag, but QUIT is not an SQL Server command. You can stop execution with an RETURN, and only 'OFF' is printed.

QUIT is not a T-SQL statement that executes conditionally but a SQLCMD command processed by the utility before the batch is sent to SQL Server. From the SQLCMD documentation:

Commands are executed immediately. They aren't put in the execution
buffer as Transact-SQL statements are.

Most SQLCMD commands must be preceded by a semi-colon but QUIT is one of those that do not require one for backwards compatibility.

Huh, I didn't "read" it as a SQLCMD operator because of the lack of the leading colon (:). It looks like, however, [:]QUIT isn't supported in sqlcmd Go; wonder if that's documented.

@ThomA, same here. I had to consult the doc to see why it worked as a SQLCMD command without the colon. That's why I added the last sentence.

Oh, it's the comment after QUIT that's causes sqlcmd Go to fail... It's not seeing QUIT as the command :QUIT.

In case anyone in the future stumbles on this in the future, it looks like :<sqlcmd command> --comment causes error in sqlcmd Go across the board. There's an issue logged quite recently against :SETVAR; I added additional context that it also effects [:]QUIT. I assume this likely affects many, if not all, sqlcmd Commands in sqlcmd Go.

Then why all the downvotes if my question apparently causes so much confusion even with the pros?! ;)
